# Selenium error about video click button python

Tags: python, selenium

I want my math online video to play automatically so I've been working on selenium.
Everything is done well but the problem occurs the moment I try to play the video.
Other elements of this page appear first and then the video with play button appears.
I want to press that button automatically.

I thought my problem caused because of loading time so I tried some kind of delaying stuff.

```
implicitly_wait()
time.sleep()
```

but after that waiting, nothing happened and an error message came out.

This is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('http://eclass.seoulxxxx.ac.kr/ilos/main/member/login_form.acl')

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("usr_id")
elem.send_keys("xxxx")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("usr_pwd")
elem.send_keys("xxxx")
elem.submit()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Math_2-1 강의실 들어가기"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_id("week-4").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@src="/ilos/images/ko/btn_start_learning.gif"]').click()

time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('vc-front-screen-play-btn').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vc-front-screen-play-btn"]').click()
```

Neither of two worked.

The error message in cmd says

```
[0116/205351.565:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(537)] EGL Driver message (Error) eqlQueryDeviceAttribEXT: Bad attribute.
```

Can you see what's the problem?

Comment: @MateMrše While you edit questions please don't add `<blockquotes`> to the error trace logs. Doing so debugging becomes difficult as the _error messages_ in the _error stack trace_  gets **word wrapped**.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

Add expected condition (to be clickable) before clicking the play button:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="vc-front-screen-play-btn"]')));
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vc-front-screen-play-btn"]').click();
```

Make sure to use the imports

Comment: What do you mean? What I wanted to say is to add the import to the already existing one.

Comment: You use just one line: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="vc-front-screen-play-btn"]'))).click()`.

Comment: What i need to do is just use that code ?? I tried with this code but still doesn't work..

Comment: You need to add this code to yours, just before the `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vc-front-screen-play-btn"]').click()` line.